# Speed Impact of a WHERE Clause in a SQL Update

Tags: sql, performance, db2, where-clause

I have a very simple SQL Update command on a DB2 (IBM System I) table, which holds approx. 30 million records.

```
UPDATE tablename SET field = 0 where field > 0
```

Now, given that the field never can be < 0 *and is not nullable*, isn't the "where" clause unnecessary? **Does the WHERE clause have an impact of the duration of this process**?

From what I understand, it is unnecessary and has an impact on the speed because the database has to evaluate each record. I am trying to find this out, because I cannot run the SQLs myself and our subcontractor says it has no impact; and we don't have the knowledge to prove / falsify that.

Comment: Update 30mln records at once?

Comment: Is the column `field` indexed? If yes, probably no difference at all, if no, probably minor difference.

Comment: yes, update 30m records at once. 
and no, from what I can see the field is not indexed.

Comment: ps: I just saw there is a special sub'stackexchange' for "database administrators". is there any way I can move my topic there?

Comment: It will exclude rows where the column is null. If there is an index on that column, this might actually make it faster. If it can't be null, then I agree it won't make a difference. If you remove it, the database will need to update all rows, if you keep it, it also needs to update all rows. The major performance "problem" is usually the actual update, not finding the rows

Answer (score 2):

If the column type for `field` can be NULL it does have an impact. NULL would evaluate to false in `field > 0`. If field is set to a value only after you get some data ie lets say that field represents emails sent today and the original DBA let `field` be NULL ie for `Unknown`. If you run this

```
UPDATE tablename SET field = 0;
```

Everyone gets reset and you lose the ability to find out how many people never sent an email, ever ie.

```
select count(*) from tablename where field = NULL
```

So depending on your schema and semantics it can mean quite a bit. Note, this is an example, I'm not suggesting it's a good design or a good use for NULL.

Answer (score 1):

**Conclusion: if there is no 0 in the field column, the where only has a very small difference in runtime.
If there are a few 0's a where soon gets faster**
The where clause soon wins in speed and imo should always be in the query if there is a possibility of 0's in the field column

I made a db table with 4.967.877 rows.

I filled half of the rows with 0, the other half with 1

```
UPDATE HugeDummyTable
SET field = 0
WHERE HugeDummyTableID < 2483938

UPDATE HugeDummyTable
SET field = 1
WHERE HugeDummyTableID >= 2483938
```

The query with the where:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
UPDATE HugeDummyTable SET field = 0 where field > 0
```

gives result:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 1829 ms,  elapsed time = 1842 ms.
(2483940 row(s) affected)
```

Resetting the table with the same first query.
Doing the query without the where

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
UPDATE HugeDummyTable SET field = 0
```

Gives this result:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 2765 ms,  elapsed time = 2791 ms.
(4967877 row(s) affected)
```

So I think the where makes the query faster.

**EDIT after comments: Filled the column 'field' with random numbers**
To make sure I'll be using the same table with the 2 try's I make a backup.

```
Update HugeDummyTable
SET field = ABS(Checksum(NewId()) % 100000)
```

Taking a look at how much 0's I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(field)
FROM HugeDummyTable
WHERE field = 0 
"45"
```

Running the query with the where:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
UPDATE HugeDummyTable SET field = 0 where field > 0

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 3313 ms,  elapsed time = 3325 ms.

(4967829 row(s) affected)
```

Restored table, reran without where:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
UPDATE HugeDummyTable SET field = 0

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 3094 ms,  elapsed time = 3121 ms.

(4967877 row(s) affected)
```

The difference is smaller, but still there. The where seems to cut off a bit of time, even with only 45 records difference.

**Edit 2: tested with no 0's**

This time there is no 0 in the field column
Without where

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 3109 ms,  elapsed time = 3238 ms.
```

With where

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 3172 ms,  elapsed time = 3337 ms.
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why this would be the case, though?

Comment: You should randomize the order of the records with `1s` and `0s` before running the benchmark.

Comment: @Jordumus if you use the where clause you are updating half the number of rows.

Comment: @SeanPearce True, so in fact, this test isn't exactly what OP is asking. Because OP has no "real" condition.